# Drupal Feature pushed to staging site

Tags: drush, features

I am just getting into drupal features and wanted to make sure I understood something.

I updated my drupal features. Used Git Flow to finish the branches and create a release.
I pulled the new release branch to the staging server.

My question is after I checkout the release branch and run drush fl - I see the features I worked on and committed as overwritten.

I  know on my local if I want the changes I run drush fu to update them. However I thought I remembered that it is the opposite on the staging server. I did run drush fd to get the diff but still learning to read that better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an existing feature and you are changing some configurations which are stored in the feature, you have to update your features

```
drush fua
```

does an update on all enabled features. After that you deploy your features (propably using git) an then you have to accept the changes done to your feature on the production side.

```
drush fra
```

(feature revert all) does the trick.

A better explanation is here: https://drupal.org/node/582680